# Missing driver for printer - adobe postscript

Tags: printing, software, driver, postscript

I have a [Panasonic Workio 190 Printer](http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/mfp/dp-190/index.html).

It doesn't seem like there is a Mac driver (I'm on Mavericks). The only thing there is, is a [Adobe PostScript Driver](http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/mfp/dp-190/ps/download.html#02-5):

I've never come across this kind of driver before and I don't want to go and install the wrong thing. Is it saying that this driver would allow the printer to work with my Mac, and are there any disadvantages to using the Adobe PostScript Driver? It seems like the only option I have at the moment.

Any input would be much appreciated as to whether this is the software I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly with the [link here](http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/mfp/dp-190/ps/download.html#02-5) you have to download and install this software: `Mac OS X 10.1 (PPD File)`.

After the installation of the file: `PPDInst.dmg`, I suggest you to install the printer from the `System Preferences > Printers & Scanners > (add a new printer by pressing + button)` and you should not have problem for the printer's driver.

Comment: FYI a PPD file is a "Postscript Printer Description" file that tells the built-in generic Mac Postscript printer driver (and any postscript driver actually) the technical details and specs for that particular printer allowing the generic postscript driver to print correctly to any Postscript printer that you have a PPD for..

Comment: It says PowerPC programs are no longer supported.

Comment: @Jimmy Accordingly with this [link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4850187?tstart=0). Power PC applications are not supported in Lion (10.7) and later. Thus you need to upgrade that software (if the printer is quite old maybe you'll not be able to find updated software) or go back to Mac OS X 10.6.8 or as last option buy a new printer.